# How to run 2 jenkins server with different port in same machine at the same time?

Tags: jenkins

I want to run jenkins with both 8080 and 8090 port at the same time. Is it possible?

I have tried to add both ports in jenkins.xml, but it didnot work through. Even though i have tried to add duplicate arguments line also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run two different instance of server at the same time with the following step:

1. Open command prompt and then type this for you first insurance of jenkins server

   ```
   java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
   ```
2. After the server ran successfully then open another command prompt and run jenkins server with different port:

   ```
   java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090
   ```

You can access jenkins servers with these addresses at the same time:

```
http://localhost:8080

http://localhost:8090
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for below as well: Like jobs in 8080 shouldnot be visible in 8090.